# DbGeography.FromText - Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial140.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, dbgeography

[image]

I have tried to copy spatial140 from packages folder "\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types...\nativeBinaries", in Visual Studio build is a success, not found some error.

But when run the project, I got that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try to Change the status of `spatial140.dll` to `Copy if new`and`Content`.

[image]

Comment: This can't work for me. But I have solved the issues, must copy spatial140.dll to bin folder.

Comment: Sure, thank you. Sorry for late the notice.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is bad, but I have solved the issues, must copy spatial140.dll to bin folder.

Comment: Instead of posting the same answer as the other person, I suggest you to accept it :)